# Deserializing date string in DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss.fff format from XML

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, xml-serialization

My program receives data from a device in XML.  The device returns date times as a string in DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss.fff format.  How do I deserialize this into a `DateTime` object, even though the local machine is set up for the US English culture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

```
DateTime.ParseExact(s, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff",
                    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Note that the case is important

- `MM`: month
- `mm`: minutes
- `HH`: Hours (24-hour)

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) method

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff",      
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Also you should use lowercase `dd` for days, and `yyyy` for year.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) or [`TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) with that format string - this should produce a `DateTime` instance.

The main difference between the two is that `ParseExact` will throw an exception if not successful and `TryParseExact` will return a boolean indicating whether the parse succeeded.